# Java Sockets slow image transfer

Tags: java, sockets

I have been writing images with the following line of code :-

```
ImageIO.write(shot,"JPG",client.getOutputStream());
```

This works well when its a single file but when i try to write multiple files immeaditly to stream, it lags my images, is there any better alternative other than ImageIO that can speed up the transfer without the lag?

Comment: have you tried converting them to bytes?

Comment: Can you post the full code that you're using so that we can perhaps replicate the issue and advise further?

Comment: JPG needs compression, this can't be immediate... Why don't you put the writing code into a thread?

Comment: May be you don't need to uncompress (while load) and then re-compress the image? Just send the JPG content as byte array (if you have access to it and the images are not generated on-the-fly).

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès i have it in a thread but it had been delaying a bit, solved it now, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Wrap a `BufferedOutputStream` around the socket output stream.
- Wrap a `BufferedInputStream` around the socket input stream.
- Use a non-compressive image format such as PNG.